# TimerEvent Dispatcher Error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, actionscript

I've got an Error when I run this code

```
var timer4:Timer = new Timer(6500);**strong text**
timer4.addEventListener(TimerEenter code herevent.TIMER,onTimer4);
timer4.start();

function onTimer4(e:TimerEvent):void{

    var bg2:Bg_2 = new Bg_2();
    bg2.x = 470;
    bg2.y = 470;
    addChild(bg2);

    TransitionManager.start(bg2, {type:Fade, direction:Transition.IN, duration:2, easing:Strong.easeIn});

    removeEventListener.(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTimer3);        
}
```

Can anybody help me understand why I'm getting this:

> TypeError: Error #1123: Filter operator not supported on type builtin.as$0.MethodClosure.
>       at Transisi_BGUTAMA_fla::MainTimeline/onTimer4()
>       at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
>       at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,  first, you have some invalid code (not sure if that is just a copy paste error or your actual attempted code).

Take out:   `**strong text**`  & change `TimerEenter code herevent.TIMER` to `TimerEvent.TIMER`.

Now that that's out of the way, on to your actual error.

The error is being cause by this line:

```
removeEventListener.(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTimer3);
```

You need to take out the period after `removeEventListener`. So it should look like this:

```
removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer3);
```

As an asside, you probably want to stop your timer as well when you remove the listener, and remove the listener from the actual timer object (which I'm assuming is called timer3):

```
timer3.stop();
timer3.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer3);
```

Comment: Thankyou verymuch what you explain absolutely 
 is solve my problem, and surely i got what you mean
once again Thankyou,